# cUrl WebIOPi error 403: Request Forbidden

Tags: pi-2, webiopi, curl

As a Mension, I'm doing some testing in RPi. The final objetive it's to control a motor and some sensor from Internet/Smartphone.

I was searching for information and I decided to use WebIOPi because seems pretty cool.

So,I wanna to make a client using the REST API, so first I'm trying with cUrl to make some testing.

The problems begun when I tried to change the GPIO or get some information. So a set a HTTP POST for example:

```
curl -v -X POST -u webiopi:raspberry http://10.42.43.112:8000/GPIO/2/function/out
```

And the output is this:

```
*   Trying 10.42.43.112...
* Connected to 10.42.43.112 (10.42.43.112) port 8000 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'webiopi'
> POST /GPIO/2/function/out HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.42.43.112:8000
> Authorization: Basic d2ViaW9waTpyYXNwYmVycnk=
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 403 Channel 2 is not allowed
< Server: WebIOPi/0.7.1/Python3.4
< Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 07:22:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 481
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 403</p>
        <p>Message: Channel 2 is not allowed.</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: 403 - Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.</p>
    </body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

At the moment, I don't seek out anything helpful, So if you know something I missed and wanna help I'll be grateful.

And I tried again with the advices of @SteveRobillard as this (output) : 
quique ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL and it doesn't work,

```
quique@quique-Vostro-3500:~$ curl -v -X POST http://10.42.43.112:8000/GPIO/2/function/out
*   Trying 10.42.43.112...
* Connected to 10.42.43.112 (10.42.43.112) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /GPIO/2/function/out HTTP/1.1
> Host: 10.42.43.112:8000
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* HTTP 1.0, assume close after body
< HTTP/1.0 403 Channel 2 is not allowed
< Server: WebIOPi/0.7.1/Python3.4
< Date: Fri, 25 Sep 2015 08:17:28 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 481
< 
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
        <title>Error response</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Error response</h1>
        <p>Error code: 403</p>
        <p>Message: Channel 2 is not allowed.</p>
        <p>Error code explanation: 403 - Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.</p>
    </body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

The same issue :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved!!

I finally resolved this problem it was a bad patch of the WebIOPi 0.7.1, so only I installed this patch: .groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webiopi/RGtrRfFJMKY and everything works fine :D